# Array in object comes back as undefined when accesing directly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is a React Component which was given an array of objects(main_object) in which one of it's elments was another array of objects(secondary_object). When printing the main object in console.log the array is visible but when trying to print the array of secondary objects it returns undefined but if I access another variable of the main object it returns it.

Code:

```
render(){
   const fleets = this.props.fleets;
   console.log(fleets[1]);//works
   console.log(fleets[1].name);//works
   console.log(fleets[1].ships);//undefined
}
```

Output:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvk7W.png)

Edit: Used my actual code instead of example code

Comment: As you can see, there is no `secondary_objects` property on the element, which is why it's undefined.

Comment: Don't trust `console` when you expand it to show you that state of the object at the time of the `console.log`. It retrieves that information asynchronously. So what probably happened is this: the `ships` property was added *after* you executed `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to recreate your environment. Here I mimicked the `this` by referring the global `window` object. And, as you can see, it works in the way that the `.ships` property is listed as the array it actually is.

```js
window.props={fleets:[
  {},
  {f_faction:1,
   id:1,
   members:["one"], 
   name:"Capital Fleet",
   owners:["owner1"],
   ships:[{a:1,b:2},{a:5,b:4},{a:7,b:8}],
   x:789, y:2897, z:-23}
]};

function render(){
   const fleets = this.props.fleets;
   console.log(JSON.stringify(fleets[1]));//works
   console.log(JSON.stringify(fleets[1].name));//works
   console.log(JSON.stringify(fleets[1].ships));//lists array!
}

render()
```

@trincot's advice that console.log output of objects is asynchronous might be very relevant here. Therefore, if you want to get the content of an object *at a specific time*, you should take a "snapshot" of it. One way of doing that would be through `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
 render(){
   const fleets = this.props.fleets;
   console.log(JSON.stringify(fleets[1]));
   console.log(JSON.stringify(fleets[1].name));
   console.log(JSON.stringify(fleets[1].ships));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `JSON.stringify` I was able to see that the problem was with the async creation of the array.

I fixed up all my async code and now it's working fine.